# Youtube video not working on my site

Tags: php, html, iframe, youtube

I have used Iframe for showing youtube video but when i put below type of link video will not showing and when i use the link directly on browser address bar it work .

My Code

```
 <iframe width="448" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHNNMj5bNQw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Link :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHNNMj5bNQw

and When i edit this link then it will work on my iframe code like.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHNNMj5bNQw

to

http://www.youtube.com/v/jHNNMj5bNQw

Please let me know what the problem.

Comment: have you tried with autogenerated code from youtube? `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/jHNNMj5bNQw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`. The only difference is in the link. There's added `embed` phrase.

Comment: No i have just copy the url from youtube and put in Iframe

Comment: Try with that example which I pasted in comment above and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS

**<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/jHNNMj5bNQw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>**

Comment: If i use this link then why i put the question buddy.Users don't know which type of link put in site. They have just copy the Youtube video URL and put in the  text box

Comment: and they have put this type of link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHNNMj5bNQw and this type of links is not working like (v="")

Comment: url that you used in your example is not the actual video url for iframe

Comment: yes this is example url but user have put this type of url that's the problem

Comment: In that case you should use you tube api to fetch that video or you can show your user a preview while he insert the url and ask them to continue only if it is working

Comment: Use link and Iframe in html file. Iframe don't work and link is working on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear on what you seem to be looking for. Ashish's answer correctly answers your question but only in the comments you mention the textbox and that your users will input the URL.

You can use Javascript to quickly parse the video Id out of the user supplied link and concatenate it in your iframe element like this.
First you may add your textarea with and `id` so you can fetch its value in JS later:

```
<textarea id="videoURL" name="name" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
```

Then you add a button calling your function `onclick` like this:

```
<button onclick="embedVideo()" name="button">Embed Video</button>
```

Set an iframe with an id sou you can easily alter the `src` attribute on the JS.

```
<iframe id="embeddedVideo" width="1280px" height="720px" src=""  title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Write the javascript function that will coordinate everything:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // define the function with name that is called onclick
  function embedVideo() {
    // get the value from the textarea using its ID
    let link = document.getElementById("videoURL").value;
    // parse the video ID from the URL
    let videoId = link.split("v=").pop().split("?")[0];
    // set the src attribute in the iframe by concatenating the video ID after the standard youtube embed endpoint 
    document.getElementById("embeddedVideo").setAttribute("src", "https://youtube.com/embed/" + videoId);
  }
</script>
```

And there you go.

Comment: By the way, the reason that the URL doesn't work is because the YouTube embed endpoint (https://youtube.com/embed) is different from the YouTube URL (https://youtube.com/watch?v=). If you just put that in the iframe, YouTube servers will refuse to connect.